# How to start a Java Web application using Http Plataform Handler on IIS?

Tags: java, asp.net, tomcat, iis

Based on this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/ I followed the instructions step by step, but with no success. I already have a ISS 10.0 server and I tried:

- Downloaded and Installed HttpPlataformHandler x64 -https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler
- Same for Tomcat 8 - http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi
- Updated server.xml file - HTTP connector port=**${port.http}**
- Got a .war project from http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/pebble/pebble-2.6.4.zip?download and put in Tomcat webapps.
- On ISS Manage, I added a new WebSite, informing the name and the physical path where my project is (tomcat, .war, web.config...)
- Web.config:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Execute, Script">
          <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" 
               modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
       <httpPlatform processPath="C:\dev\javasites\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\bin\startup.bat" 
                     arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                     stdoutLogFile="\\?c:\dev\javasites\log.txt">
       <environmentVariables> 
         <environmentVariable name="JRE_HOME" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111" />
         <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="c:\dev\javasites\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.39" />
       </environmentVariables>
      </httpPlatform>
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
  ```
- Finally, when I try to access localhost/ or localhost/pebble, on the tab the message shows "waiting for localhost" and the request never ends.

I already tried:

- Turn off the Firewall.
- Give full permission to ISS_ISRS and IUSR.
- Give full permission to the project folder.
- AccessPolicy (system.webServer/handlers) with Read, Write, Execute, Script permissions.

Without any error code from request, I can't see where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, based on my understanding, it sounds like that you want to use IIS HttpPlatform handler to start up a Tomcat instance, but I don't know the environment whether host on Azure App Service or just host on Windows.

If your needs is to manually configure & use a Tomcat within control on Azure App Service, I think the document [`Upload a custom Java web app to Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload) is very helpful for you to upload a Tomcat instance & Java WebApp to `wwwroot` path and configure `web.config` to make it start up with IIS.

But if you just want to configure Tomcat with IIS for starting up & working, you need to refer to the document [`The Apache Tomcat Connectors - Web Server HowTo`](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) for IIS to try to do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just went into another approach installing apache tomcat with different port. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Fells Did you use Azure website? If so, you could not install the other tomcat instance with different ports besides 80 & 443, because it's [Networking Restrictions/Considerations](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#networking-restrictionsconsiderations) for Azure Website.

Comment: Hi @Peter. Nope. It's a dedicated server that uses IIS. I did a test and worked without any conflict. Do you know if there is any implication?

Ps. I removed the Azure tag from my question post.