# iis 8 java and .net web services

Tags: java, .net, tomcat, web, iis-8

I currently have web services written in .NET being hosted on a Windows 2012 server with IIS 8. The .Net services were written by someone else. My experience is mostly in Java so I figured I'd write my web services in Java. Now I'd like to host the Java web services on the same server. I know I can't use Java web services directly in IIS 8 but is there a way to have Tomcat hosted through IIS 8 and then have the Java web services routed through IIS 8 to Tomcat? I've seen the Tomcat connectors being used but the main thing I want to do is host both Java and .Net web services.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a Java Web application using Http Plataform Handler on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830922/how-to-start-a-java-web-application-using-http-plataform-handler-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

Both IIS and tomcat are web application servers. When they work, what they do is to listen to http requests on some specific port and handle them. So, as long as they are configured on different ports, there should be no problems.